# How to reference first entry in keyless table in Lua?

Tags: lua, lua-table

I have a table defined like so:

```lua
local foo =
{
    bar =
    {
        { ['baz'] = "A sample string", ['qux'] = 128 },
    },
}
```

Obviously, the is a small part of a much larger algorithm.  I'm having trouble referencing the first entry in table `bar`.

```lua
print("foo.bar", "type", type(foo.bar), "value", foo.bar)
print("foo.bar.first", "type", type(foo.bar[0]), "value", foo.bar[0])
```

If I try a simple print, like shown above, the second print outputs `nil` for type and value.

```lua
foo.bar type    table   value   table: 000001DF39D19D20
foo.bar.first   type    nil value   nil
```

FYI, if I put it in a loop using the `pairs()` or `ipairs()` functions, I can get at the `baz` and `qux` members without any problem, but I'd prefer not to us a loop here.  Is this possible?  How may I reference the first entry in a keyless table without looping?

Comment: Because in Lua arrays are 1-based.

Comment: In the general case, when table is not necessarily an array, you can call `next` to return the first pair of key / Value (but which one you get is **unspecified**)